# Change Django Authentication Model password field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I am trying to modify my Django project authentication so I can use my own User model.

I have got it working so far, however I am unable to override the "password" field. I want to change the name to "password_hash".

I have tried this manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email_address, full_name, password=None):

        if not email_address:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email_address = self.normalize_email(email_address),
            full_name = full_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email_address, full_name, password_hash):
        user = self.create_user(email_address,
            password_hash=password_hash,
            full_name=full_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

However I get the error `TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'`.

How do I stop create_superuser() from expecting "password" and change it to "password_hash". For username I did it by changing the `USERNAME_FIELD`, however nothing in the documentation suggests a similar method for the password.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Is there a typo? you retrieve `password_hash` arg but you set `password` arg..

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah that was a typo however it didn't solve the problem. The solution is to override `def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)`. I'll answer it as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to override this method in my new user model:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
```